# Remove a Movieclip from an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs6

I'm very new to ActionScript 3.0, so be gentle. :P
I'm making a simple 'custom gun' program where you can cycle through the different parts of the weapon to give it a unique appearance.  For example, you have the 'barrel' and the magazine'.  Each part is a movieclip with frames for the different options.

Parent Movie Clip: Barrel
Frames within are labeled, each with an MC.
Each MC in there has 4 layers labeled "Paint, Details, Metal, Light".

I have an array of the current parts:

```
var paintList:Array = new Array (Base.Paint, Bar.BarStandard.Paint, Mag.MagStandard.Paint /*, etc.*/);
```

Now what I need is to remove a specific piece from that array.  So for the above example, how would I just remove the Bar.BarStandard.Paint and add instead Bar.BarExtended.Paint?

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help!  :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with arrays and removing values from within arrays you use **splice**

Using splice;

```
arrayName.splice(indexValue, deleteCount)
```

- arrayName you replace with the name of your array
- indexValue you replace with the position that the value you want to remove from the array falls
- deleteCount is the amount of values you want to delete

Example with your code;

```
var paintList:Array = new Array (Base.Paint, Bar.BarStandard.Paint, Mag.MagStandard.Paint, etc.);
```

The value you want to replace is the 2nd value, therefore

```
paintList.splice(2,1)
```

And to add another value to that position.

```
arrayName[indexNumber] = newValue;
```

Again with your code;

```
paintList[2] = Bar.BarExtended.Paint;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  Using this I could keep the parts in a specific index within the array, so it at least would be easier if I do go this route.  Thank you. :)